# Theory of physical causality?

Tags: general-relativity, statistical-mechanics, definition, causality

There's a fairly well-developed tradition of "causal structure" in relativity theory and in relativistic quantum theory, which essentially determines which events in spacetime are "causally connected" to one another. Essentially, an event in the rear light cone of another can hypothetically be its cause; otherwise it cannot be.

On the other hand, there is now also a pretty well-developed *statistical* theory of causality, well known to practitioners in machine learning, that formalizes causal relationships between statements, in terms of Bayesian graphs and so on.

I am looking for a physical theory that unifies these two notions, by formalizing and ideally quantifying the extent to which two physical events are actual, instead of potential, causes of one another.

One would expect such a theory to assign "zero" causation to causally disconnected events in the relativistic sense. But presumably not all events in another event's past are, in fact, important "causes". E.g. the fact that my fingers are striking the keys on my keyboard is presumably a more important "cause" of you reading this text than is the Moon's position 10,000 years ago, even though both events are in your rear light cone.

Has such a theory been developed? Could anyone briefly explicate it, or point to references which do? I'm looking for a classical theory here mostly, but a quantum generalization (presumably relating 'causation' to 'entanglement' or something) would also be interesting.

Comment: Can you share some links about the statistical theory of causality?